# Why is google analytics return different number of results with same parameters?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

**Reporting API v4**

I am a developer. I have my clients google adwords and analytics. I have been using adwords and analytics report API for almost a year now.

I am also using https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/. The query builder. For comparing if I have retrieve the right amount of data.

I don't know if its an error or not but its acting weird.

**Try number 1** using https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/
I tried to add 2 metrics and 7 dimensions. This Account ID, contains 1 million data in only 1 month. I know this because I retrieved 1 million in a range of july 25, 2018 - august 16, 2018.

Then, here's the interesting part. I run the query again with the same parameters, it retrieves 5999 results. I did it again it returns 1 million. The results keep changing. I thought its the error in my code but its also happening in the query builder.

What do you guys think? is it a bug or not?

You can try this if you have more than a million data.

I know its not related to coding. But Google Analytics doesn't have forums just like Adwords.

**Try number 2** using this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet

 this is my request

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "endDate": "2018-08-16",
          "startDate": "2018-07-16"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "name": "ga:dimension2"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:dimension3"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:dimension1"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:adPlacementDomain"
        }
      ],
      "pageSize": 5,
      "viewId": "********",
      "samplingLevel": "LARGE",
      "metrics": [
        {
          "expression": "ga:entrances"
        },
        {
          "expression": "ga:newUsers"
        }
      ],
      "includeEmptyRows": true
    }
  ]
}
```

The return of rowCount is sometimes 2111 and then 1000000.
This my response json with 1million result:

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": [
          "ga:dimension2",
          "ga:dimension3",
          "ga:dimension1",
          "ga:adPlacementDomain"
        ],
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:entrances",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:newUsers",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "(other)",
              "(other)",
              "(other)",
              "(other)"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "120834",
                  "68730"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "1000025873.1532426892",
              "1532426891790.o9z84x",
              "2018-07-24T11:08:15.449+01:00",
              "unknown"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "0",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "1000025873.1532426892",
              "1532426891790.o9z84x",
              "2018-07-24T11:08:17.589+01:00",
              "unknown"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "0",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "1000025873.1532426892",
              "1532426891790.o9z84x",
              "2018-07-24T11:08:31.809+01:00",
              "unknown"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "0",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "1000025873.1532426892",
              "1532427045552.p38pk78",
              "2018-07-24T11:09:06.43+01:00",
              "unknown"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "0",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "totals": [
          {
            "values": [
              "158626",
              "90225"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rowCount": 1000000,
        "minimums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "0",
              "0"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "maximums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "120834",
              "68730"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "isDataGolden": true
      },
      "nextPageToken": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

another response example when i have less 1million results:

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": [
          "ga:dimension2",
          "ga:dimension3",
          "ga:dimension1",
          "ga:adPlacementDomain"
        ],
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:entrances",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:newUsers",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "1002211166.1531434756",
              "1531762918308.fjnj7pa6",
              "2018-07-16T18:41:58.307+01:00",
              "mobileapp::2-com.forsbit.spider"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "1002211166.1531434756",
              "1531771001486.jawfrpz8",
              "2018-07-16T20:56:41.482+01:00",
              "mobileapp::2-com.forsbit.spider"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "1002211166.1531434756",
              "1531772475507.7n4w2qzb",
              "2018-07-16T21:21:15.503+01:00",
              "mobileapp::2-com.forsbit.spider"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "1002211166.1531434756",
              "1531859165986.zl7we6a5",
              "2018-07-17T21:26:05.977+01:00",
              "mobileapp::2-com.forsbit.spider"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "1002211166.1531434756",
              "1531859632678.dz7hccsa",
              "2018-07-17T21:33:52.673+01:00",
              "mobileapp::2-com.forsbit.spider"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "1002211166.1531434756",
              "1531861026792.kw71ngx9",
              "2018-07-17T21:42:31.667+01:00",
              "mobileapp::2-com.forsbit.spider"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "totals": [
          {
            "values": [
              "2111",
              "233"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rowCount": 2112,
        "minimums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "0",
              "0"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "maximums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "1",
              "1"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "isDataGolden": true
      },
      "nextPageToken": "6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am experiencing similar issues and would be interested if there is a solution that might help me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have kept all the queries intact. Double check just to make sure.

Second step would be to check for sampling. Check the field `samplingSpaceSizes` and `samplesReadCounts` in the response for sampling. If these fields were not defined that means no sampling was introduced.

Comment: how do i set them in query builder?  https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: In `batchget` request set `samplingLevel` to `LARGE`. Find more about it here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics

Comment: I have tried it. But it seems its return different numbers. I have updated my question, you can check the json request above.

Comment: do you see `samplingSpaceSizes[]`in your response?

Comment: No. I am not seeing it. I also updated my question with response json.

Comment: check in the response when rowcount is less, the response added in question has row count of 1000000.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178672/discussion-between-ichimaru-and-ankdasco).

Comment: i updated my question with another response, the less 1million
I still dont have the samplingSpaceSizes